# Creating an object with variable Key in Twig

Tags: twig

Using twig I want to create an object with a variable key & value.

If I do

```
{% set k = "TheKey" %}
{% set v = "TheValue" %}
{% set object = { k : v } %}
```

the result is { k: "TheValue" } instead of { "TheKey": "TheValue" }

Is it possible to do in twig what you can do in Javascript?

```
var obj = {
    [myKey]: value,
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should surround the key attribute with parenthesis:

```
{% set k = "TheKey" %}

{% set v = "TheValue" %}
{% set object = { (k) : v } %}

    {% for key, value in object %}
        <li>{{ key }}: {{ value }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
```

Check this working fiddle: https://twigfiddle.com/a61r9f

Comment: But this is an array, not an object.